# Performance consideration running C#.net winForms from network share

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I understand that you can run .NET application from network share.  I have done so many times and it works.  My question is relating to performance.  Will the app run slower with 10 concurrent users than with 2?  Is there some magical number of concurrent users that provides a rule-of-thumb saying if you have more than 20 users don't host the app this way?

Does each client copy the app and run from the copy in a temp folder?  Or are they each accessing the source file?  Where does `Application.ExecutablePath` point in this situation?

EDIT: There is no Access database involved.  All data persistance will be handled through an SQL server database with stored procedures, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable is copied from the Windows share to the memory of the workstation computer, and executed there.  There shouldn't be *any* discernible difference in performance, *assuming the executable itself has no sharing issues.*

Of course, if your app is sharing a database, there might be concurrency issues there, but that has nothing to do with where the workstation gets the executable.

`Application.ExecutablePath` will point to the folder on the network share.  `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` should still point to the workstation.

Comment: -Sounds like no downside.  What am I missing?

Comment: @MAW74656 Seems you are missing nothing here. As Robert said, the only cavat are files from the network share like e.g. databases or in general anything being read from and written to frequently. I had _very_ bad experiences with running MS Access databases from a network share.

Comment: The executable might not be designed to be shared in this manner.  It might be assuming (rightly, in most cases) that it owns the folder from which it is executing, so it might be persisting some data in that folder.  If that's the case, it might break if you let others try and run it from the same folder.

Comment: Ok, but will `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` and similiar to point to the local user's computer?

Comment: @UweKeim: The front-end portion of a multi-user Access application should never be executed from a shared location. The back-end database can be shared from a single point (assuming the application has been properly split into its front-end, back-end counterparts).

Comment: @MAW74656: Those `SpecialFolder` values should still point to the user's local machine.

Comment: @UweKeim -Actually, we have some legacy access apps running that way, and it works.... but is slow and buggy.  That's why when I make something new I'm not using Access.

Comment: @MAW74656 I used to maintain a large multi-user Access application. The overall performance and stability of the application improved dramatically when we upsized the back-end database to SQL Server Express.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -Not surprising, I'd dump it all into our SQL Server database server if I could, but priorities and time prevent it, so I'm living with it for now.